# how i can read image file in c by block?

Tags: c

i would like read image in c but in limit byte it means read  by n bytes until end all image

```
FILE *stream ;

FILE *stream1;

stream= fopen(pFile, "rb");

//when stream still bytes in stream

do

{

 numread = fread( stream1, sizeof( char ), 64, stream );

//treat the stream1 

}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are actually asking but probably you need to find out the size of the file (for example by using `fseek`), then you need to allocate a memory block of exactly this size using `malloc`, and then you need to read the file into that memory block.  
BTW: you open stream and then you read from stream1 is this a typo ?

Comment: how i can read from the block n bytes not all? how i can read from a block? for example read 0...64 after 65...128... until end of block

Comment: stream1 is not a FILE*, it is your buffer (char *). but before you have to alloc (64 * sizeof(char)) bytes. If you can 'treat the stream1' in the while loop, no need to store data on multiple blocks.

Comment: i understand thank you ...but after i allocate the buffer then how i can read from the buffer after i copy the whole of file to buffer how i can read from the buffer?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need this:

```
FILE *stream1;

stream1 = fopen(pFile, "rb");

if (stream1 == NULL)
{
  printf("Failed to open file");
  return 1;
}

int numread;

do
{
  char buffer[64];
  numread = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 64, stream1);

  // now buffer contains the 'numbytes' bytes you have read

} while (!feof(stream1)):
```

Comment: thank you ... this code will detected the EOF of the file?

Comment: @yag_md actually when numread is 0 I assumed that EOF was encountered. I modified the answer and now I'm using the `feof` function that returns TRUE if the previous `fread` has encountered the end of file.

Comment: i have image contains 262 144 bytes it mean 262 144/64 = 4,096

Comment: OK and so what ? As far as I understood you want to read 64 bytes, treat them, read the next 64 bytes treat them etc. until the enf of file. Please state clearly what _exactly_ you want to do.

Comment: @yag_md sorry, but your last comment suggests that you are lacking the very basics of the C language. Read about pointers and arrays in any C textbook or in any C tutorial.

Comment: @yag_md why only reading 64 bytes at a time instead reading all in one ?

Comment: i want to calulate probabilty to every char in a block exmple 64 not all file